# SEQUELIZE - How to Get All Assosciated Objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have a many to many association like this:

```
Squad.belongsToMany(Member, {through: Membership});
Member.belongsToMany(Squad, {through: Membership});
```

How do I find all the Squads, and for each squad, show me the squad name and an array with the Members that each squad has associated with it?

**UPDATED WITH WHAT I'VE BEEN TRYING AND WHAT RESULTS I GET:**

I've been trying things like this:

```
Squad.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Member,
        required: true
    }]
}).then(squads => {
    // The rest of your logics here...
});
```

Here's a sample of what I get:

```
  { id: 3,
    name: 'Knicks',
    city: 'NYC',
    state: 'NY',
    'members.id': 3,
    'members.name': 'Carmelo',
    'members.city': 'NYC'
  },

  { id: 3,
    name: 'Knicks',
    city: 'NYC',
    state: 'NY',
    'members.id': 2,
    'members.name': 'Penny',
    'members.city': 'Orlando',
    'members.state': 'Florida'
  }
```

But what I want is not multiples of the same object and individual member info.  I'm trying to get something more like this:

{
 id: 2,
 name: 'Lakers',
 members: [ memberInfo, memberInfo, memberInfo]
}

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you modeled your relations correctly, then you should be able to do something like

```
Squad.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Member,
        required: true
    }]
}).then(squads => {
    // The rest of your logics here...
});
```

Comment: Thanks @JasonWihardja, but could you see the update in my original post? I tried what you recommended, but I'm not getting what I'm looking for.  Would you let me know your thoughts on that?